# Angular 6 querying components from a projected view container

Tags: angular, angular6

Here is an example for the problem: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vvpr21
When you create components dynamic way with ComponentFactoryResolver then ContentChildren decorator of the parent ignores them. I am trying to solve this issue from an other point of view.

I want to query for an InjectionToken and get the reference of the component through contentchildren from that.

```
export const ChildToken = new InjectionToken<ChildComponent>('ChildToken');
@Component({
  ...
  providers: [{
    provide: ChildToken,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => ChildComponent)
  }]
  ...
}) export class ChildComponent{ ... }
```

So I can import ChildToken where my ParentComponent is and try the following:

```
@Component({..}) export class ParentComponent{
  ...
  @ContentChildren(ChildToken) children:QueryList<ChildComponent>;
  ...
}
```

Here I get this error from ts:

"Argument of type 'InjectionToken' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Function | Type'.
  Type 'InjectionToken' is not assignable to type 'Type'.
    Property 'apply' is missing in type 'InjectionToken'."

After that I also tried this:

```
@ContentChildren(ChildToken.ngInjectableDef) children:QueryList<ChildComponent>;
```

Here I got this error from js:

"Uncaught Error: Can't construct a query for the property "children" of "ParentComponent" since the query selector wasn't defined."